# Mixing together DDD with Event Sourcing

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

I can't get my head around concept of mixing together DDD with ES. I consider events as being part of domain side. Given that there is no problem with publishing them from repository to outside world and keeping models pure and simple. But aside from that there must be possibility of replaying them back on particular aggregate. This is where my problem occurs. I would like to keep my domain models pure and simple objects that remain lib/framework agnostic.

To apply past events on aggregate the aggregate must be aware of being part of ES structure (wherefore it would not remain pure domain object). As main job of aggregate is to enfroce some bussines invariants that may evolve over time it is impossible to apply old events using aggregate API. For instance, there is aggregate Post with child entities Comments. Today Post allows 10 Comments to be added, and method addCommnet() guards that rule. But it is not used to be that way all time. One year ago user was allowed to add up to 20 Comments. So appying past events may not meet current rules.

Broadway (popular PHP CQRS library) works around the problem by applying events without any prevalidation. Method addCommnet() just checks it against our invariants and then processes appling events. Applyinig event itself does not do any further checking. That is greaat but I perceive that as high level of integration in my domain models. Does really my domain model need to know anything about infastructure (which is ES style of saving data)?

EDIT: 
To state the problem with the simplest words possible: is there any opportunity to get rid of all those applyXXX() methods from aggregate?

EDIT2:
I have written (bit hacky) PoC of this idea with PHP - [github](https://github.com/ayeo/pure-es)

Answer (score 2):

> I can't get my head around concept of mixing together DDD with CQRS.

From the sound of things, you can't quite get your head around the mix of DDD and *event sourcing*.  CQRS and Event Sourcing are separate ideas (that happen to go together well).

> Today Post allows 10 Comments to be added, and method addCommnet() guards that rule. But it is not used to be that way all time. One year ago user was allowed to add up to 20 Comments. So appying past events may not meet current rules.

That's absolutely true.  Notice, however, that it is also true that if you had a *non* event sourced post with 15 comments, and you try to make a "rule" now that only 10 comments are allowed, you still have a problem.

My answer to this puzzle (in both styles) is that you need a slightly different understanding of the responsibilities involved.

The responsibility of the domain model is *behavior*; it describes which states are reachable from the current state.  The domain model shouldn't restrict you from being *in* a bad state, it should prevent good states from *becoming* bad states.

In version one, we might say that the state of a `Post` includes a `TwentyList of Comments`, where a TwentyList is (surprise) a container that can hold up to 20 comment identifiers.

In version two, where we want to maintain a limit of 10 comments, we don't change the `TwentyList` to a `TenList`, because that gives us backward compatibility headaches.  Instead, we change the domain rule to say "no comments may be added to a post with 10 or more comments".  The data *schema* is unchanged, and the undesirable states are still representable, but the allowed state *transitions* are greatly restricted.

Ironically enough, a good book to read to get more insights is Greg Young's [Versioning in an Event Sourced System](https://leanpub.com/esversioning).  The lesson, at a high level, is that event versioning is just message versioning, and state is just a message that a previous model left behind for the current model.

Value types aren't about rule constraints, they are about *semantic* constraints.

Keep in mind that the timelines are very different; behaviors are about the *now* and *next*, but states are about the *past*.  States are supposed to endure much longer than behaviors (with the corresponding investment in design capital that implies).

> Does really my domain model need to know anything about infrastructure (which is ES style of saving data)?

No, the domain model should not need to know about infrastructure.

But events aren't infrastructure -- they are *state*.  A journal of `AddComment` and `RemoveComment` events is state just like a list of `Comment` entries is state.

The most general form of "behavior" is a function that takes current state as its input and emits events as its output

```
List<Event> act(State currentState);
```

as we can always at an outer layer, take the events (which are a non destructive representation of the state, and build the state from them.

```
State act(State currentState) {
    List<Event> changes = act(currentState)
    State nextState = currentState.apply(changes)
    return nextState
}

List<Event> act(List<Event> history) {
    State initialState = new State();
    State currentState = initialState.apply(changes)
    return act(currentState)
}

State act(List<Event> history) {
    // Writing this out long hand to drive home the point
    // we could of course call act: List<Event> -> State
    // to avoid duplication.

    List<Event> changes = act(history)
    State initialState = new State()
    State currentState = initialState.apply(history)

    State nextState = currentState.apply(changes)

    return nextState;
}
```

The point being that you can implement the behavior in the most general case, add a few adapters, and then let the plumbing choose which implementation is most appropriate.

Again, separation of responsibilities is your guiding star: state that manages what is, behavior that manages what changes are allowed, and plumbing/infrastructure are all distinct concerns.

> In the simplest terms: I'm looking for opportunity to get rid of many applyXXX() (or similar in languages with overloading methods) methods from my aggregate

`applyXXX` is just a function, that accepts a `State` and an `Event` as arguments and returns a new `State`.  You can use any spelling and scoping you want for it.

Comment: I am ok with changing bussines rules over time, that is perfectly fine. I'm looking way to applay past (and incorect today) events from outside of aggregate. I consider events as being part of my domain, agregates emits/register/publish them. I dont want to have apply() methods in my aggregate becouse I percieve it as being part of ES (and my domain care nothing about that). To conclude, I wonder if is possible to not involve directly my aggregates with replaying events. I cant do it from oustide the aggregate however due to business cohesiveness validation.

Comment: In the simplest terms: I'm looking for opportunity to get rid of many applyXXX() (or similar in languages with overloading methods) methods from my aggregate :)

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I'm a [CQRS framework](https://github.com/xprt64/cqrs-es) guy.

> Broadway (popular PHP CQRS library) works around the problem by applying events without any prevalidation.

That's the way every CQRS Aggregate works, events are not checked because they express facts that already happened in the past. This means that applying an `event` doesn't throw `exceptions`, ever.

> To apply past events on aggregate the aggregate must be aware of being part of ES structure (wherefore it would not remain pure domain object)

No, it doesn't. It must be aware of its past events. That is good.

> Today Post allows 10 Comments to be added, and method addCommnet() guards that rule. But it is not used to be that way all time. One year ago user was allowed to add up to 20 Comments. So appying past events may not meet current rules.

What keeps you `aggregate` from *ignoring* that event or to interpret differently than 1 year ago?! 
This particular case should make you think about the power of CQRS: writes have a different logic than reads. You apply the events on the aggregate in order to validate the future commands that arrive at it (the write/command side). Displaying those 20 events is handled by other logic (the read/query side).

> This is where my problem occurs. I would like to keep my domain models pure and simple objects that remain lib/framework agnostic.

CQRS make possible to keep your aggregates pure (no side effects), no dependency to any library and simple. I do this using the style presented by [cqrs.nu](http://cqrs.nu), by yielding events. This means that aggregate command handlers methods are in fact [generators](http://php.net/manual/ro/language.generators.syntax.php).

The read models can also very very simple, plain PHP immutable objects. Only the read model updater has dependency to persistence, but that can be inversed using an `interface`.

Comment: Be aware of frameworks that force your Aggregates to extends some classes, interfaces, use some static class method or global object.

Comment: That is my problem exactly, the framework that interferes with  my domain models. I can hadle changing bussines rules, that is ok. I am looking way to applay past (and incorect today) events from outside of aggregate.

Comment: @ayeo in my framework, every Aggregate expose an `applyXXX` method per event and a `handleXXX` method per command; the command handler `yields` events that are `applied` onto the Aggregate itself.

Comment: I understand this approach but I need to seperate this out. I want to have dedicated command handler classes (that is easy) and dedicated "event appliers". It is important to me because I dont want wire my domain models (eg aggregate) with implementation details (cqrs/es). Afaik domain should not depend on infrastructure. So if I decide to persist my data other way my bussines models should remain untouched. Im not sure if it is even possible :)

Comment: @ayeo this is called a style. There are many styles. My style fits perfectly with commands and events. The classic OOP style does not fit perfectly with commands and events, it needs a translation layer. In my opinion, mixing  the two styles introduces accidental complexity.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is very short. Indeed, it is event-sourcing that you struggle with, not CQRS.

If handling of some event changes over time, you have two scenarios really:

1. You are fixing a bug and your handler should really behave differently. In this case you just proceed with the change.
2. You got some new intent. You actually have a new handling. This means that in fact this is a different event. In this case you have a new event and new handler.

These scenarios have no relation to programming languages and frameworks. Event-sourcing in general is much more about the business that about any tech.

I would second to Greg's book recommendation.

Comment: you thoroughly right it is ES concern. I've read the book. My problem is about moving applyXXX() metods outside aggregate. When the methods are placed insideI can apply past events without checking them against current requirments (eg max post numeber, if someone has added 20 in the past and 10 is max today - that is fine). Problem (as I percieve that) with replying events by dedicated class is it must use aggregate api (which will validate against current logic). My problem is not about changing bussines rules. It lies more on technical level. – ayeo 14 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that you want to validate events when they are applied, but apply and validation are two different stages of aggregate action. When you are adding comment by method addComment(event), there is your logic to validate and this method is throwing event, when you reply event this logic is not checking again. Past event can not be changed, and if your aggregate throws exception with reply event something is wrong with your aggregate. That's how I understand your problem.